# OXID: Too many redirects in frontend

Tags: php, oxid

I can access the backend normally, but if i open the frontend it redirects me with this GET parameters

> index.php?cl=oxstart&execerror=unlicensed&redirected=1

Why does this happen, I've tried to clear cache but no progress.

From the EXCEPTION_LOG:

```
oxException (time: 2017-08-30 15:22:23): [0]: no compatible connector adapter for shop version  found 
 Stack Trace: #0 /html/core/oxutilsobject.php(185): oxUtilsObject->_getObject('d3shopcompatibi...', 0, Array)
#1 [internal function]: oxUtilsObject->oxNew('d3ShopCompatibi...')
#2 /html/core/oxfunctions.php(375): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/shopcompatibility/d3shopcompatibilityadapterhandler.php(0): oxNew('d3ShopCompatibi...')
#4 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/shopcompatibility/d3shopcompatibilityadapterhandler.php(0): d3ShopCompatibilityAdapterHandler->getCurrentAdapterClassName()
#5 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/shopcompatibility/d3shopcompatibilityadapterhandler.php(0): d3ShopCompatibilityAdapterHandler->getShopAdapter()
#6 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/models/d3_oxmodule_activecheck.php(0): d3ShopCompatibilityAdapterHandler->call('oxmodule__activ...', Array)
#7 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/d3install_updatebase.php(0): d3_oxmodule_activecheck->d3RefreshModuleMeta()
#8 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/d3install_updatebase.php(0): d3install_updatebase->_refreshModuleMeta()
#9 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/models/d3install.php(0): d3install_updatebase->isUpdateRequired()
#10 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/controllers/admin/d3_navigation_modcfgupdate.php(0): d3updateinstaller->getRequiredUpdates()
#11 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/controllers/admin/d3_navigation_modcfgupdate.php(0): d3_navigation_modcfgupdate->_doModCfgUpdateRequired()
#12 /html/application/controllers/admin/navigation.php(61): d3_navigation_modcfgupdate->_doStartUpChecks()
#13 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/controllers/admin/d3_navigation_modcfgupdate.php(0): Navigation->render()
#14 /html/core/oxshopcontrol.php(483): d3_navigation_modcfgupdate->render()
#15 /html/core/oxshopcontrol.php(388): oxShopControl->_render(Object(d3_navigation_modcfgupdate))
#16 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/controllers/d3_oxshopcontrol_modcfg_extension.php(0): oxShopControl->_process('navigation', NULL, NULL, NULL)
#17 /html/core/oxshopcontrol.php(148): d3_oxshopcontrol_modcfg_extension->_process('navigation', NULL, NULL, NULL)
#18 /html/modules/_d3modcfg/modules/controllers/d3_oxshopcontrol_modcfg_extension.php(0): oxShopControl->start(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#19 /html/modules/nfc/nfc_301redirects/extended/nfc_oxshopcontrol.php(25): d3_oxshopcontrol_modcfg_extension->start(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#20 /html/core/oxid.php(32): nfc_oxshopcontrol->start()
#21 /html/index.php(19): Oxid::run()
#22 /html/admin/index.php(20): require_once('/html/index.php')
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your license key is invalid. Check log/exception_log.txt

Comment: I had updated question and added error log. Not looking like the wrong licence.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the shop version? The error is coming from an installed module `_d3modcfg`. Try to disable the d3 modules.